# Optimize Apache for delivering video

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd

I have my local Apache Server dedicated to delivery video (not streaming) so users connected to it locally (LAN) can play video files as if they were local:

in a linux client with mplayer:

```
mplayer http://192.168.0.1:1234/movies/mymovie.mkv
```

in a windows client with Media Player Classic HC:

```
mpc-hc64.exe http://127.0.0.1:1234/movies/mymovie.mkv
```

I tested in the host computer (127.0.0.1) to rule out any blame on network delay.

It works fine but when seeking the movie position and at the beginning of the playback it takes a little while, as if it was buffering. (I mean, what buffer if I am on 127.0.0.1?)

My question is, what parameters should I add to **httpd.conf** to optimize this kind of 'upload' so the playback won't freeze when seeking?

*The testing server is an i7 running Windows 10 x64 + Apache 2.4*